My Manager continually says things that aren't true, often in a defensive tone
My goal is to stay at this job and succeed, building a good relationship with my manager and co-developers. I'm a software engineer and relatively new at the company.
I'm used to being direct and open about issues our code & processes have. At this company, though, I think I keep "stepping in it" by mentioning problems I spot. My manager has told me, for example, all obviously, plainly incorrect:

We don't have feature creep on this project—there haven't been any new requirements.
We already have a technical-such-and-such expert for helping with such-and-such.
Our dev process X doesn't show any conflicting messages—it's all straightforward and easy.

You can see, these untruths always lean in the direction of "there's no problem here."
I usually naively respond directly to her assertion, but that has the strange effect of her skipping the point and getting into the weeds of side issues.
Any ideas?

You can see, these untruths always lean in the direction of "there's no problem here." - We don't know if her statements are true or not, as we don't know if your statements are true or not. We can't attest to the truthfulness of either of you, and can't give you an answer.

Are you able to report issues that don’t involve dealing directly with your manager otherwise it seems crystal clear, your manager would rather have you not report these issues, and allow the dedicated QA to report them instead. It’s not clear how any of those statements are not true, even if untrue, best not muddy the waters with the individual who determines how well you are doing in a given year.

Your examples are so darn general and confrontational that it isn't a surprise that the manager is getting annoyed with you. Are you looking to learn how thing are done at this company or expecting them to learn how you think they should be done? Every so often I have to remind an employee that our company has been successful for a number of years. Ideas are always helpful, being told how wrong we are, isn't.

And if you're being confrontational, you should expect people to sound defensive in response, no matter who is ultimately correct. It sounds as if you are trying to use that to justify your attack. It doesn't.

Question seems related to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/198779/how-to-deal-with-a-boss-that-is-using-non-related-arguments-in-a-dissent, however the issue there is that responses are not so much untrue but rather unrelated to the question. The effect of not getting the desired effect/actions you are looking for is the same, however. The issue in this case may be caused by (toxic) company culture of ignoring issues until they blow up. Being a whistleblower in such culture won't make you popular. Options: keep your head down and stop caring, or keep caring and be ready to leave.

Your three examples might indeed mean that your boss is covering up problems and being defensive. But they might also mean that you are making mistakes and need to start listening to your boss. We don't have enough information to know which, but the second case doesn't seem to have occurred to you, so let me tell some stories to illustrate it.

Long ago, I was asked to add a "seniority report" to a system. The requirements were pretty minimal, just kind of first name last name department, amount of seniority in years and days. The bug report came back "why is this in alphabetical order?!" Apparently "everyone" knows that seniority reports are in seniority order. To me, this was a new requirement. I hadn't known it, I was only told it when the report was done. Everyone else would have said "there are no new requirements." If you feel surrounded by new requirements while your boss says that doesn't happen, consider this alternative explanation: there are things everyone else knows that you don't know, and it's hurting you.
"We already have a technical-such-and-such expert for helping with such-and-such" is crystal clear "stay in your lane" instructions. You are being told you know less about such-and-such than you think, and your suggestions are not welcome. Failing to understand this can be a career limiting move.
You finding something conflicting while others find it straightforward and easy could just be that they are familiar with it in all its complexity and have forgotten it was confusing at first, but it could also indicate a "skills issue" for you.

I recommend you try, for a few days or a week, considering the possibility that what your boss is saying is true, and indicates a weakness on your part -- that there are things you don't know or can't do well, and need to improve. This may not be the case, but I recommend you consider it. When one of these "untrue and defensive" things happen, pause, and ask yourself if there was a weakness in your own skills, could that explain this seeming contradiction? Then you can ask questions, not to prove your boss wrong, but to improve yourself.
Examples:

is this a new requirement? I was not aware of it. Did I miss it? Does everyone else know it was supposed to do that? Can you help me figure out why I didn't know it was supposed to do that?
if a process is causing me problems can I ask the such-and-such expert about it, or should I go through someone on our team?
is there a such-and-such book/course/tutorial I can use to get a better understanding of the process?
I can't reconcile A and B but everyone seems to think it's straightforward and easy. How can I understand the system better? Why are A and B not in conflict?

Sometimes (probably most times) these polite and non defensive questions will lead to genuine improvement for the person asking. They will discover they aren't reading the whole email, they zoned out in the meeting, they didn't check the wiki, or whatever. Occasionally, they will reveal cases where the asker is actually not doing it wrong, and because the askee isn't feeling defensive or accused of untruths, the askee may well change a process or decision in light of this new information.
What won't work, whether your boss is lying or not, is stomping around complaining that you have to deal with a lying boss. That's not how businesses and teams handle differences of opinion, background, or skill levels.

Adding to this, it can be helpful to phrase things as questions even when you're sure you have a technical understanding. "I wasn't aware the system worked that way, how does that handle  or ? This doesn't lead to ?". This not only changes the social context from "ego contest" to "truth discovery", it encourage details instead of deflection - a chance for anyone involved to determine if there were any gaps in their knowledge regardless of how accurate their initial statement was.

Especially when you are a new person in a development group, it is better to not be the negative voice in the room. Trying to correct issues in process or procedure is better done when you have more experience with the group and your manager.  Eventually, you may come up with better ways to present the problems so that they are better received and more likely to get the action that you want.
My advice would be to ride out any issues you find.  Get the reputation of being the person that gets things done correctly the first time.  You don't need to say "I told you so", but you need to have people know that they should have listened to you.  If you can master a less optimal system, then people are more likely to listen when you give a better solution.

If you are new at the job, why would you call out your boss and challenge her? No one likes a know-it-all smarty=pants, because that's what you nay be coming across as. You need to hunker down and do a fantastic job.  Then they will value your opinions.
If you spot an issue with the code, then say something like "I noticed this issue in the code and it might have these ramifications.  Would you like me to look at it" to your boss.  Tone it down even more if you are able to.
Or if there is freedom to fix what you want or if you have time left, then take the initiative and fix one of them.
